# How can I embed my website app on other websites?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I hope someone could explain me some stuff, since I'm quite new in web development...
While creating my own portfolio website I wanted to embed a **music player widget**, so I embedded Soundcloud through the iframe. I realized I wanted to customize it more, due to my color pallet used in the website. Since Soundcloud doesn't let you do that, I got an idea for a website where a user could insert a youtube URL, choose the width and height of the container, choose colors, box-shadow, display background image over the video, border radius... After a couple of days I finally managed to create this website (with the use of YouTube API), where a user puts in a YouTube URL and basically customizes his music player and watches the changes on as he's tweaking the settings.

**But now I have absolutely no idea on how to make this web app embeddable**. My idea is that after the user customizes everything he gets some code which he can put onto his own website, where the music player will appear. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something with an `<iframe>` HTML tag. However to produce the correct height, width, etc. you would require a backend-- say in PHP or something to generate the specific code snippet.

You would also have to keep in mind responsiveness so say on a phone or tablet the media shows/works. CSS Media queries, or relative CSS units such as percentages, are your friend here.